# Reading files in JavaScript using the File API trhown "TypeError: e is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fileapi

I'm trying to append files to `FormData` to handle files upload through AJAX and after read and keep finding for a solution **without need to use external plugins** I found [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and I'm trying to use it on my code so I made this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.smart-form').on('submit', function (e)
    {
        var files;

        e.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
        e.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

        if ($(".state-error").length < 1) {
            // Create a formdata object and add the files
            var data = new FormData();

            // Check for the various File API support.
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                // Grab the files and set them to our variable
                files = e.target.files;

                $.each(files, function (key, value)
                {
                    data.append(key, value);
                });
            }

            // Create a jQuery object from the form
            $form = $(e.target);

            // Serialize the form data
            var formData = $form.serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '{{ path('update-product', {'id': id}) }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if (typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                    {
                        // Success so call function to process the form
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("ERRORS");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log("ERRORS");
                },
                complete: function ()
                {
                    // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm getting this error at `Firebug` console:

> TypeError: e is undefined

And I not able to find where is my mistake or what's happening. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyqoozb5/1/) is a Fiddle with test code, can any help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

The error is not the same at jsFiddle, if you take a look at `Firebug` console the error trown is this one instead:

```
TypeError: obj is undefined 
  length = obj.length,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
files = e.target.files;
```

In the link you provided, he is attaching an event handler to the change event of the file input element, not the submit button:

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

So e.target would be the file input element and e.target.files would work.

You've changed the code around, and you're calling this in the submit button click handler.  So e.target refers to the submit button, and e.target.files refers to nothing.

So change your code to this and it will work:

```
files = $('form #product_imageFile_file')[0].files;
```

See here for a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/xyqoozb5/2/